# Show a limit cycle exists for 2D ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Show that the following system of ODEs has a limit cycle
>   $$\dot{x} = 4y^3 + (x+1) - (x+1)[(x+1)^2 + y^4]
> $$
>   $$\dot{y} = -2(x+1) + 2y^3 - 2y^3[(x+1)^2 + y^4].
> $$

The way the problem is written, it seems pretty suggestive to me to look at the point $(x,y) = (-1,0),$ which turns out to be a critical point.  Making the change $x \mapsto x-1,$ we can consider the critical point at the origin for the equivalent system
$$\dot{x} = 4y^3 + x - x^3 - xy^4
$$
$$\dot{y} = 2y^3 -2x - 2y^3x^2 - 2y^7.
$$
The stability of the origin is given by evaluating 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1-3x^2 - y^4 & 13y^2-4xy^3 \\ -2-4xy^3 & 6y^2-6y^2x^2 - 14y^6 \end{pmatrix}$$
at the origin, giving the eigenvalues $\lambda = 1,0.$ Not sure if this is useful in anyway.  But from this point, I am stuck.

In general, when trying to show that a limit cycle exists, usually the Poincare Bendixson theorem is invoked.  This theorem states sufficient conditions to conclude that a limit cycle exists, but I do not know how to use it rigorously (with a computer, plot the vector field, and if there exists an annulus-like region $R$ called a "trapping region" where the vector field only points into the region, then there exists a limit cycle in $R$).

Perhaps I am overthinking it and there is an easier way to go about this problem.  Any suggestions, hints, solutions, all is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: From staring at numerical phase portrait I got the feeling that sticking to Poincaré-Bendixson might be a good idea. It seems that limit cycle stays in square $\lbrack -1, 1 \rbrack \times \lbrack -1, 1\rbrack$. Maybe it's reasonable to take some $\alpha x^{2n} + \beta y^{2m} = C$ near the origin as one part of boundary and something rectangular-like as another part of boundary?